# string to md5 hash in class using FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING

Tags: php, class, md5, sanitize

Question: Why don't these match on output?

So I have been tracking down an issue that is causing me a lot of headache I can't figure out what is causing issues with passing a shortened version of MD5 hash that is sanatized with FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING

I know it seems strange that I sanitize a md5 hash but this class is not only used in this manner and I am trying to avoid making multiple methods to do the same thing.

```
class test {
public function select($match,$debug) {
        $match1 = filter_var($match, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if ($debug == '1') {
            var_dump($match,$match1);
        }

}
}

$title = "April 2013"; // Example Title
$currentHUID = substr(md5($title), 0, 12); // Convert string to UID not for encryption just comparison first 12 char of MD5 Hash

$test = new test();
$test->select("'$currentHUID'",'1');
```

> ***RESULTS:*** string(14) "'8860d4398c9b'" string(22) "'8860d4398c9b'"

Comment: So, what was the real question?

Comment: 14 character string reads 22 chars... That's not weird to you?

Comment: works for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/fEuEzQ

Comment: try $test->select($currentHUID,'1');

Comment: @Dagon First of all that is not what I am doing exactly and you also do not shorten the md5 hash. All my tests doing basic things like what you did result it the correct response. Something in this configuration is causing weirdness and that's what I need to figure out. I need to leave the single quotes around it because it will be passed to MySQL

Comment: check again, i updated the example, and sure add the quotes in the query not in the function call

Comment: its the quotes - see my example here:http://codepad.viper-7.com/JvMkD5

Comment: @cryptic ツ Seems even after using str_replace to remove the whitespace from the title it still gives a mismatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending single quotes with your value and these get encoded.

If you use:

```
$match1 = filter_var($match, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
```

The result will be the same as the input.

[Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Wkp4pD).

Also see the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php).

Comment: I did read the manual as I normally do but I missed the Flag thanks for your help!